# Why was Romulan Ale illegal?

Tags: star-trek

Was Romulan Ale illegal because of a trade embargo between two warring states, providing material support to the enemy ala Cuban cigars?

Or is it because the Federation nanny state thinks alcohol in general should be banned,  ala Prohibition (at the same time making the black market sale of alcohol lucrative)?

Or is it because something specific about Romulan Ale that makes it illegal? Toxicity? After-effects? Promiscuity?

Comment: Promiscuity? Huh?

Comment: Moral Guardians tend to equate alcohol with sex...

Comment: @Richard, <snort>.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Romulan Ale](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_ale) is illegal due to a trade embargo. In an episode of DS9 [Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inter_Arma_Enim_Silent_Leges_(episode)) the crew shares a toast of Romulan ale stating that the embargo has been lifted due to a Federation/Romulan alliance during the Dominon War.

> **CRETAK:** *A glass of Romulan ale, Doctor?*
>
> **BASHIR:** *Thank you, Senator.*
>
> **ROSS:** ***The trading embargo has been officially lifted***, if you were wondering.
>
> **BASHIR:** *It hadn't crossed my mind, actually.* - <sub><sup>[Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/565.htm)</sup></sub>

We also know the embargo is replaced upon the Romulans some time after the Dominon War as it is again illegal by [Star Trek: Nemesis](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html).

> **WORF:** *Romulan ale should be illegal.*
>
> **GEORDI:** *It is, old chum.*
>
> **WORF:** *Then it should be **more** illegal.*

Comment: He doesn't say _old chum_ in the "broadcast" version. To be fair, the entire final line was also cut.

Comment: That reminds me *so much* of marijuana legalization in Alaska. (Even though it has been quasi-legal since the 70s)