# What is known about Klingon aphrodisiacs?

Tags: star-trek

Inspired by [this question about Romulan ale](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91045/why-was-romulan-ale-illegal), I have a question about Klingon aphrodisiacs.  After receiving a bottle of Romulan ale as a birthday present from Bones in *Star Trek II*, Capt. Kirk points out that the ale is illegal, and a little later, he wonders aloud what will be inside the doctor's second present:  "Klingon aphrodisiacs?"

Romulan ale became a running gag of sorts in *Star Trek*.  It featured notably in *Star Trek VI* and has been referenced numerous other times.  It was even sold in the real world.  Like Kirk, I got some as a birthday present.  It was the worst beer I have ever had.

I assume that nobody is selling Klingon aphrodisiacs licensed by Paramount, but have such substances ever actually appeared in *Star Trek* canon?  Given how revolting Klingon food is supposed to appear to viewers, I cannot help but wonder what luxuries used for more intimate purposes might be like.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Aphrodisiac

Comment: I find myself perfectly capable of not wondering about the subject.

Comment: WORF: No. Men do not roar. Women roar. Then they hurl heavy objects. And claw at you.  WESLEY: What does the man do? 
WORF: He reads love poetry. He ducks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every culture has a version of aphrodisiac. The only other time that a specifically Klingon aphrodisiac was mentioned in canon was in the Voyager episode, Author, Author, in the second version of the fictional holonovel, which is modified by Tom Paris. The "Doctor" gives it to the Seven of Nine (who is named something like Two of Three or whatever). It comes in an injectable form-- his own "special blend."

Just because Klingon food moves about doesn't mean their aphrodisiacs do. The human versions of that are outside what we normally eat for food, so, and this is speculation, but it could be something as simple as an herb or combination of herbs. We tend to go with animal parts, but that doesn't mean they would...

Since there is no canon on this, anything we come up with would be purely speculative.

Comment: You might wish to add that that Klingon aphrodisiac seen in Author, Author was a fictional creation and may not even be real.

Comment: @Valorum Sorry I thought holonovel gave it away...

Comment: Don't get me wrong. It's a good find and worthy of a mention, you just might want to go a little further in pointing out that many of the elements of the novel are overblown or fictionalised.